# copy file to clipboard

Tags: delphi, clipboard, filestream

i want copy a binary file into the clipboard, so when user is right clicking on the screen can see the paste option enable. software is handeling the paste part very well just i need to copy file into the clpboard.
this is my first time working with clipboard i tried this code

```
Procedure CopyStreamToClipboard( fmt: Cardinal; S: TStream );
  Var
    hMem: THandle;
    pMem: Pointer;
  Begin
    S.Position := 0;
    hMem := GlobalAlloc( GHND or GMEM_DDESHARE, S.Size );
    If hMem <> 0 Then Begin
      pMem := GlobalLock( hMem );
      If pMem <> Nil Then Begin
        try
          S.Read( pMem^, S.Size );
          S.Position := 0;
        finally
          GlobalUnlock( hMem );
        end;
        Clipboard.Open;
        try
          Clipboard.SetAsHandle( fmt, hMem );
        finally
          Clipboard.Close;
        end;
      End { If }
      Else Begin
        GlobalFree( hMem );
        OutOfMemoryError;
      End;
    End { If }
    Else
      OutOfMemoryError;
  End;
```

which is not working im not sure but i guess its because of the handle that im passing to the method

```
CopyStreamToClipboard( CF_HDROP, fileStream );
```

i wanted to work with SetClipboardData too but couldn't found any useful example. thanks

Answer (score 6):

The [`CF_HDROP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx#CF_HDROP) format cannot hold actual file data, only filenames.  Read MSDN's documentation for more details about `CF_HDROP`:

[Shell Clipboard Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx)

For what you are attempting to do, you would need to either:

1. save the `TStream` data to a temp file, and then put that filename on the clipboard using `CF_HDROP`.
2. use [`CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx#CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR) and [`CFSTR_FILECONTENTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx#CFSTR_FILECONTENTS) instead of `CF_HDROP`.  Then you can provide an [`IStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034.aspx) to your data (look at the RTL's [`TStreamAdapter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamAdapter) class for wrapping a `TStream` inside of an `IStream` implementation).  However, you cannot do this with [`SetClipboardData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051.aspx), you would need to implement the [`IDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688421.aspx) interface and use it with [`OleSetClipboard()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686623.aspx) instead.  See MSDN for more details:

   [Shell Data Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776903.aspx)

   [Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904.aspx)
3. register a custom clipboard format using [`RegisterClipboardFormat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649049.aspx), then you can store whatever you want on the clipboard, including an entire file (it is not advisable to put large amounts of data on the clipboard, though).  However, the other app that is pasting the data would also have to use `RegisterClipboardFormat()` when calling [`GetClipboardData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039.aspx) to access your custom data.

Either way, the code you have shown is only suitable as-is for #3.

Comment: thank you so much, that help me lot, because i had no Idea about the clipboard now i know generally how is it working, so im gonna check the app to see how it is handling the pasting data then i can decide which way I'm going to copy the file into the clipboard